# Два связанных <select> без js. Возможно ли?

Tags: php

У меня есть сейчас список `<select>`, который функционирует для вывода таблиц с информацией. Нужен ещё , который будет списком ников. То есть, выбрал ник, причину - тебе вывело по данному нику причину, которую выбрали.

```
<form action="#" method="post">
    <select name="Color" style="width: 177px;">
        <option value="Red">Приветствие</option>
        <option value="Green">Диагностика</option>
        <option value="Blue">Решение вопроса</option>
        <option value="Pink">Прощание</option>
        <option value="Yellow">Все критерии</option>
        <option value="Zero">Конфликт</option>
    </select>
    <button class="head_logout" type="submit" name="osubmit">Выбрать фильтр</button>
</form>
```

Сам код списка `select`, если нужен будет функционал - готов буду прикрепить на codepen какой-нибудь, ибо слишком много там мусора.

Comment: Никакими связанными селектами тут и не пахнет. В чем проблема вывести сразу два селекта, и выбрать из одного ник, а из другого причину?

Comment: Связанные селекты - это выбрать сначала сначала страну, а потом город.

Comment: @Ипатьев Ник выбрать, потом причину - вывести по нику, выбранную причину - разве не связанные? Есть вариант показать, как сделать это без связанности? Я бы был очень признателен.

Comment: Зачем выбирать причину потом? почему нельзя сразу?

Comment: @Ипатьев Не сильно могу понять к чему идёт диалог, сейчас нужен концепт именно такой, выбираем ник в одном селекте, в другом - причину и выводим по нику - причину. Если есть предложение и время показать, как быстро и по другому - я бы был благодарен, очень сильно.

Comment: делаем форму с двумя селектами. выбираем в одном причину, во втором - ник. Нажимаем субмит. *что здесь непонятного?*

Comment: и потом на сервере `WHERE nick = 'NICK' and cause = 'ПРИЧИНА'`.

Comment: @u_mulder Скорее всего у меня сейчас не работает логика и мозг, нету ли возможности накидать хотя-бы пару строк - как это реализовать? В голову лезет только эти связанные формы и больше ничего.

Comment: Если у вас не работает мозг - дождитесь пока заработает и приступите к задаче заново.

Comment: @u_mulder Берем две формы и одну кнопку, по одной кнопке просто делать выводы запросом, который вы указывали? Ну это примерно...

Comment: Форма __одна__, на ней __два__ селекта.